# Implement the Event-Dispatch-Thread in the right way

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I need a Event-Dispatch-Thread in my programm.

I want go from this:

```
public Controller {
    this.login= new Login(this);
}
```

to this:

```
public Controller {
    Runnable guiCreator = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            this.login= new Login(this);
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(guiCreator);
}
```

I know where the mistake in the second version is. But the Login(Controller controller) constructor needs the controller reference...
How i do this?

Comment: Why do you want/need to make that change?

Comment: This programm sends files to a server. The server receives this files in one seperate thread per file. If i comment the GUI out, then it works. If i don't comment the GUI out, then the file is not sending.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Controller.this` to refer to the outer/top level instance of the class

```
public Controller() {
    Runnable guiCreator = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            login= new Login(Controller.this);
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(guiCreator);
}
```

Comment: @assylias Neither would the OP's ;)

Comment: Don't works, because the "login" in "this.login= new Login(Controller.this);" is red underlined.

Comment: login is a private member-variable of Login.java.

Comment: Sorry, check update.  And `login` can't a `private` member of `Login`, otherwise you can't assign it from within the context of `Controller`...

Comment: Glad we got it sorted